# WPF app with touch screen, mousedown event is blocked until you lift finger or move your finger amount

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

Here is my sample project.
**In MainWindow.xaml**, I register PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown".

```
<Window x:Class="TouchProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TouchProblem"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
        Background="Black"/>
```

And add debug log in Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown():

```
private void Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("windown preview mouse left button down");
}
```

**In MainWindow.xaml.cs**, I disable wpf tablet support after InitializeComponent() function in constructor by using [DisableWPFTabletSupport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642479/how-to-disable-wpf-tablet-support-in-surface-4-pro)

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     DisableWPFTabletSupport();
}
```

After disable WPF Tablet Support by using DisableWPFTabletSupport, when I touch down on screen, mousedown event is blocked until you lift finger or move your finger amount as following gif.

[image]

I want to keep using DisableWPFTabletSupport, **How do I can get PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event immediately after touch down as usual?**

Comment: Did you try to handle the `TouchDown` event?

Comment: @mm8 Yes, I did. But TouchDown event is not raised any more if you use DisableWPFTabletSupport() method

Comment: I observe the same thing (and worse, it works until it doesn't and I can't figure out the trigger).  I had some success with this NativeTouchDevice class but it broke other events (like clicks on buttons).  It was part of an old library called Blake.NUI (that was hard to track down).  You might see if it helps you.  https://github.com/freakimkaefig/collaborative-tabletop-music-search/blob/518f092d19c27d28acf8996e136df81c0b38221d/app/libs/Blake.NUI/Blake.NUI.WPF/Touch/NativeTouchDevice.cs